# what's wrong in my function "openfile"

Tags: c, file, fopen

```
void openfile(FILE *fichier,char *str){
    char path;



    path=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    fichier = fopen(&path,"r");

    if (fichier)
        printf("fichier chargé avec succes \n");
    else
        printf("ERREUR");

}
```

i call the function in this way:

```
openfile(fichier,cc);
```

and cc contain "C:\Documents and Settings\Oussema\Mes documents\test.txt"

it return : "ERREUR"

Comment: Learn to use a debugger to solve this problems yourself. You will have a very hard time programming when you need to ask a question every time something does not work as expected.

Comment: Among many things, your function is not using the input variable `str`. And you are allocating just one character for `path`. Note: Compiler could inform you about unused variables if you set the right flags.

Comment: @nvoigt I used a debugger but I didn't get any thing clear

Comment: @Antonio when I print path and str it print the same string

Comment: What are you using the `path` for if the `str` contains the file to open?

Comment: @user694733 i do it and the same probem

Comment: @oussemos Please show the full code with your function AND the printing commands you mention. Show also the output you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
void openfile(FILE *fichier,char *str){

    fichier = fopen(str,"r");

    if (fichier)
```

Apart from path being a char, not a pointer and unecessary, if openfile is void, it should terminate the program with a non-zero exit value, not return.  Spewing messages, without even specifying a filename isn't very helpful to anyone.

Comment: @oussemos Then perhaps you didn't pass in a correct file name ? You'll need to look out for leading or trailing whitespace characters, escape the \ character if the filename is entered in your code as a verbatim string etc. What you need to do when you have an error such as this is to create a small, complete example that anyone can compile and run, and then post that code, or at the very least tell us what you're doing.

Comment: @oussemos: if you printed out name of what you tried to open on failure, and checked it was exactly what you expected, then mistakes would be obvious

Answer (score 2):

This code makes nothing sensible.

- The parameter `str` is ignored.
- `path` is assigned a pointer to an array of *one* character
- The parameter `fichier` is ignored. There is a value assigned to it in the function. This can't be used to return a value.
- The first parameter to `fopen` is a pointer to garbage.

Try this and look why it is different.

```
void openfile(FILE **fichier, char *str)
{
    if (NULL == fichier) return;

    *fichier = fopen(str, "r");

    if (*fichier)
        printf("fichier chargé avec succes\n");
    else
        printf("ERREUR");
}
```

*Edit:*

I would prefer to return the value as return value. In that case it's not much more than a verbose version of the function `fopen` itself.

```
FILE* openfile(char *str)
{
    FILE *fichier

    fichier = fopen(str, "r");

    if (NULL != fichier)
        printf("fichier chargé avec succes\n");
    else
        printf("ERREUR");

    return fichier;
}
```

Comment: +1 I agree, apart from the useless `NULL != ` in pointer checks.

Comment: still have prob , the same prob

Comment: Is it perhaps "the same prob" as in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844252/whats-wrong-in-my-code)?

Comment: @user694733 The language C allows any term that can be evaluated to an `int` in the `if` clause. So it's possible to write `if(fichier)`. I want to write code that I can read, therefore I use a boolean expression in the `if()` clause. The `if` doesn't check whether there is a pointer but if the pointer has as specific value. I know, YMMV.

Comment: @harper Well, a matter of taste really. I just think that `if(!resource)` is easier/faster to read as *"if no resource"*, than *"if NULL equal to resource"*.

Comment: @user694733 Yes there are some cases where that's true, e.g. `fopen()`. But this can be error-prone with other functions, like a huge set of Windows API functions like `CreateFile`, the pendant to `fopen`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx So you have some cases where a `if(!function_result)` may work and others don't. I don't trust the implicit type conversion and write a boolean expression.

Answer (score 0):

No sense in the code at all. What do you try to do ?
Couple of notes...

```
void openfile(FILE *fichier,char *str){
```

What's the purpose of `str` if you don't use it ? Maybe you meant it to be the path to open the file with..

```
path=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
fichier = fopen(&path,"r");
```

you just defined path and let him have one byte in memory (enough for ONE character) - no sense in that - you should have defined a lot more room in it as it is supposed to be a string (fopen gets a pointer to a string !!!) and strings in C are built from characters and NULL value at the end. The pointer `path` has no sense as:
1. It's not initialized after using malloc on it, it's just a garbage value.
2. You're using it as a pointer to a string in `fopen` but it has only 1 byte size so you can only put NULL in it and no more, so it means - no way to open file.

```
if (fichier)
    printf("fichier chargé avec succes \n");
else
    printf("ERREUR");
```

Here I would suggest you'll just make the function to return an void* that'll return NULL if everything went fine or anything else if something went wrong so you'll manipulate the function better and it won't just print things on the screen without your permission :P

Comment: Addendum : he stores the pointer returned by malloc in a char.